# Use existing SQLite db in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I need to use an existing SQLite db that is will be shared by a Python app in an iOS application.

How do I integrate the db into my project? I have a framework that's integrated into my project that acts as a controller for the app. So, I've focused on integrating the db with that. This is the code I'm trying to get to work:

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3

public class Board {
    public static let shared = Board()
    public static var db: OpaquePointer?
    
    public init() {
        Board.startDB()
    }
    
    public static func startDB()  {
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("words.db")
        print(fileURL)
        // open database
        guard sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &Board.db) == SQLITE_OK else {
            print("error opening database")
            sqlite3_close(Board.db)
            return
        }
        print(" db ok")
        return
    }
```

it's reporting "db ok" in the console, so it's getting that far. In the ViewController, I have this as the last line in `viewDidLoad()`

```
print ("board db is \(Board.getCount())")
```

that calls this, but returns "no go"

```
public static func getCount() {
    let query = "select count(*) from words;"
    print(query)
    var queryStatement = Board.db
    if sqlite3_prepare(Board.db, query, -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK{
          while(sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){
               let count = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
               print("\(count)")
          }
    } else {
        print("no go")
    }
}
```

the words.db file is stored in the same directory as the *board.swift* file, which is the files directory for the framework. The console spits out

> file:///Users/dandonaldson/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/B03E9CD5-6311-4E3C-BDC7-43CF97ACEC24/data/Containers/Data/Application/B55E3D64-CDD0-49EB-AFE4-478305DA3DE9/Library/Application%20Support/words.db

for that, which I don't know how to interpret... I guess the first question is, do I need to tell the main project that that file is a resource of some kind, and how do I go about that? Where *should* it reside?

The bigger question is, generally, what's the best way to go about this? Because the database needs to be in sync with another app, the use of CoreData hasn't been pursued, and for the moment It'll be treated as not an option...

Comment: minor edit to improve formatting

Answer (score 1):

You are opening the db in the app support directory. But what if the database hasn't been copied there yet? Then your `sqlite3_open` will create an empty database. And then, when `sqlite3_prepare` fails, you are not looking at `sqlite3_errmsg`, which would have told you *why* it failed (namely that the table was not found).

So:

- Remove the empty db in the app support directory. The easiest way is to just temporarily delete the app entirely from the device/simulator.
- Open database with `sqlite3_open_v2` with `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE`, but *without* `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`. Then a blank database will never be created accidentally.
- If open failed, copy db from bundle (assuming that's how you're distributing it with the app), and then reopen.
- If a SQLite call fails, use `sqlite3_errmsg` to get the text of the error message. This error message often offers precise info about where and/or why it failed, which is very useful when diagnosing problems.

Thus:

```swift
public class Board {
    public static let shared = Board()

    private var db: OpaquePointer?

    private init() {
        startDB()
    }

    private func startDB()  {
        let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
            .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
            .appendingPathComponent("words.db")

        // see if db is in app support directory already
        if sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
            print("db ok")
            return
        }

        // clean up before proceeding
        sqlite3_close(db)
        db = nil

        // if not, get URL from bundle
        guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "words", withExtension: "db") else {
            print("db not found in bundle")
            return
        }

        // copy from bundle to app support directory
        do {
            try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundleURL, to: fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("unable to copy db", error.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        // now open database again
        guard sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
            print("error opening database", errorMessage())
            sqlite3_close(db)
            db = nil
            return
        }

        // report success
        print("db copied and opened ok")
        return
    }

    public func getCount() {
        let query = "select count(*) from words;"
        var statement: OpaquePointer?                         // not = db

        guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
            print("unable to prepare query", errorMessage())  // if fails, print the error message
            return
        }

        defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }                 // make sure to finalize or else you will leak

        if sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW {            // in this case, since it's one row only, `if` is acceptable alternative to `while`
            let count = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0)
            print("\(count)")
        }
    }

    public func errorMessage() -> String {
        return sqlite3_errmsg(db)
            .flatMap { String(cString: $0) } ?? "Unknown error"
    }
}
```

A few unrelated observations:

- You have `shared` to create singleton instance. That's fine. But if singleton, you wouldn't generally make `init` a `public`. Make it `private` if you want this to be a singleton, i.e. to prevent creating other instances accidentally.
- Neither `db`, `startDB`, nor `getCount` should be `static`. You have have the singleton instance, so you should use that, e.g. call `Board.shared.getCount()`.
- Make sure to call `sqlite3_finalize` whenever you call `sqlite3_prepare_v2`.  Otherwise, you will leak.
- Since `init` is calling `startDB`, there's no need to expose that method. (Clearly, if you add a “close” method and later want to reopen it, then fine, make it `public`.) But as it is, it is strange to expose a method only used by `init`.

---

You said that you want to `print("board db is \(Board.getCount())")`. Well, first it should be changed to return the value. And obviously you should use your singleton.

E.g.

```
public func count() -> Int? {
    let query = "select count(*) from words;"
    var statement: OpaquePointer?

    guard sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &statement, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        print("unable to prepare query", errorMessage())
        return nil
    }

    defer { sqlite3_finalize(statement) }

    guard sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW else {
        return nil
    }

    return Int(sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0))
}
```

And then

```swift
if let count = Board.shared.count() {
    print("board db is \(count)")
}
```

If you do not want to make the return value to be optional, you could alternatively change it to a method that throws errors. Both patterns are acceptable. But you need to provide a mechanism for the caller to know that the call was successful or not.

Comment: I'm making some headway. Your comments and Ptit Xav are helping. Giving the singleton thing some thought, I realized there were some advantages to having a separate class manage the DB, and treating that as an instance. All communication to that is left to Board. 

So, that's now got it to the point where I am able to successfully open the db via the new db manager class. I've sorted out referencing the database, and it was just dawning on me that when Simulator runs, it has to copy the database (about 14Mb) to the application support directory…

Comment: That would produce the problem I'm seeing: the database opens fine, but it reads 0 rows when I read it, at init time.So, now the question is, how do I ensure that, at least in this testing environment, the db is in fact in situ? If you've got an answer, I appreciate the time you and @Ptit Xav have put into this already, but it would be helpful. I realize that this won't be an issue in deployment, since the DB will be bundled with the app.

Comment: Anticipating your answer, would it be reasonable to hard-code the URL to the db, so that it isn't copied? This could have the disadvantage that my base DB is being modified,which could mess up testing,  but the app never writes to the DB, and I could always use a copy. Really pursuing best practices here as much as anything else.

Comment: “That would produce the problem I'm seeing: the database opens fine, but it reads 0 rows when I read it, at init time.” ... no, there must be some bug in your logic, because if the database in the bundle has records and, if upon initial launch, it does not exist not in app support, so you copy it there and then open it, then your count should presumably not be 0. It’s the whole reason we copied it there. If you’re always using `sqlite3_open_v2` and always without `SQLITE_OPEN_CREATE`, then it’s impossible to create a blank database.

Comment: So, if need to figure out the bug in your logic, and I’d do that first. But (a) after you’ve fixed your logic bug; and (b) if the time to copy the 14mb database the very first time (but never again) still bothers you, you probably could open the db directly from the `bundleURL` instead, but supply the `SQLITE_OPEN_READONLY` option to `sqlite3_open_v2` rather than `SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE`.

Comment: I've posted a new answer that contains the direction I got working. I think the level of abstraction that GRDB offers helped, and the time to get the raw SQLite solution working was not worth the time. I'm just not going to use this for anything but very basic queries. If I wasn't juggling tens of thousands of words that needed to be searched very quickly, I might have just used a textfile. And if I didn't have particular update needs, I wouldn't have cared about SQLite per se, and the reuse of the db I'm using. This is the compromise that works.

Answer (score 0):

For swift you must convert the string to c string in sqlite3_prepare, also use another pointer for the statement :

```
var queryStatement : OpaquePointer?
sqlite3_prepare(Board.db, query.cString(using: .utf8), -1, &queryStatement, nil)
```

Comment: I've added that, but it doesn't change the results. I wonder if there's anything that stands out as an obvious error: e.g. : I'm trying to reference an existing file, with a 'db' extension (tried changing it, no diff). Should the file URL be an explicit reference to the location of my db file? Anything you might see would help...

Comment: Just added a new variable declaration for the statement

Comment: I did not pay attention that you mixed your class car and instance class. Set db as var (not static) and use self.db in the calls. Also in init call self.startDB()

Comment: not sure this can be done? Board is a singleton, there are no instances

Comment: This is not correct. You don’t have to convert to C string. Swift does that for you.

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements for clarity :

```
import Foundation
import SQLite3

public class Board {
public static let shared = Board()
var db: OpaquePointer?

public init() {
    self.startDB()
}

public func startDB()  {
    let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
        .url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        .appendingPathComponent("words.db")
    print(fileURL)
    // open database
    guard sqlite3_open(fileURL.path, &db) == SQLITE_OK else {
        print("error opening database")
        sqlite3_close(db)
        return
    }
    print(" db ok")
    return
}

public func getCount() {
    let query = "select count(*) from words;"
    print(query)
    var queryStatement : OpaquePointer?
    if sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, query.cString(using: .utf8), -1, &queryStatement, nil) == SQLITE_OK{
          while(sqlite3_step(queryStatement) == SQLITE_ROW){
               let count = sqlite3_column_int(queryStatement, 0)
               print("\(count)")
          }
          sqlite3_finalize(query_statement)
    } else {
        print("no go \(sqlite3_errmsg(db))")
    }
}
}
```

In viewController :

```
print ("board db is \(Board.shared.getCount())")
```

Comment: Is this a different answer? If not, edit your 1st answer and put this content there. Then delete this post.

Comment: clearly, it's not the same answer, and it's posted by Ptit Xav.

Comment: This is a different answer. The original answer was before I saw the mixing between the declarations of static var. it seemed to me that can led to mixing between instance variable and static class and variables.

Comment: as I said, there should be no instance variables, and I don't think there are. This is being used in a singleton

Comment: @DanDonaldson - When you declare a singleton, by definition that means that you are creating an instance. (A single instance, but still an instance.) So, remove `static` with the properties (other than `shared`, of course) and methods. Then you interact with them from the singleton instance. But making them `static` will unnecessarily constrain you moving forward.

Comment: Is there a strategy that would allow me to retain static on the properties, and get what I'm looking for? There are 5 other classes in this Framework that all interact heavily, that it's not my prerogative to change to solve one problem here. That's a lot of churn. Any suggestions?

Comment: First you can declare queryStateemnt as a OpaquePointer? And not equal to Board.db. The. Convert request string to cString. Finally ‘finalize’ the statement. Also try to print sqlite3_errmsg(Board.db) to know what is your problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, a bit frustrating, but many thanks to @Rob and @Ptit Xav for the persistent help. Since my requirements are very simple in use, I took a different direction. Dealing with the combination of things in play, I decided to focus on just getting a solution I could work with.

I shifted to GRDB, which is not exactly a breeze. But I got direct help from the developer/maintainer and that was enough to get me over the top. With GRDB, I can use raw SQL queries, but there's a (cryptic) system to connect app objects with table data. The code shows I'm not doing the latter.

After importing GRDB, and retaining the separate class WordDB to manage the DB, which at least gives me an interface to any updated db approach I attempt in the future, this works well enough to assure me that I can plug in the very simple queries I'll need:

```
public class WordDB {

    var dbPath : String = "words.sqlite3"
    var dbQueue : DatabaseQueue?
    
    init() {
        setup()
    }

func setup()  {
        
        var config = Configuration()
        config.readonly = true
        let filepath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "words", ofType: "sqlite3")
        do {
            dbQueue = try DatabaseQueue(path: filepath!, configuration: config)
        } catch {
            print("damnation")
            return
        }
        
        do {
            try dbQueue!.read { db in
                if let row = try Row.fetchOne(db, sql: "SELECT * FROM words WHERE id = ?", arguments: [1]) {
                    let word: String = row["word"]
                    print(word)
                }
                
                if let row = try Row.fetchOne(db, sql: "SELECT count() FROM words") {

                    print(row)
                }
            }
            
        } catch {
            print("nope")
        }
    }
…
}
```

(I wanted to reuse a database that is in SQLite, in part because it will make a multilingual product much easier, and also because frequent updates to it will happen outside the app – the main reason I did not go the CoreData route. I now have what I want.)

I was confused about where exactly the database file should reside. Because the database is read by a class in a framework, which in turn is imported into the single-view app, I wasn't clear where it should be located as a resource. At the level of the framework (which makes the most sense), or the app? In the end I simply imported in both places, and I'll figure out which is redundant later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working code for copy and open copied database file

private func startAndCopyDB()  {
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default
.url(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
.appendingPathComponent("securitymasterdatabase_db2.db")

```
    // see if db is in app support directory already
    if sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) == SQLITE_OK {
        print("db ok")
        return
    }

    // clean up before proceeding
    sqlite3_close(db)
    db = nil

    // if not, get URL from bundle
    guard let bundleURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "securitymasterdatabase_db2", withExtension: "db") else {
        print("db not found in bundle")
        return
    }
    // copy from bundle to app support directory
    do {
        try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: bundleURL, to: fileURL)
    } catch {
        print("unable to copy db", error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    // now open database again
    guard sqlite3_open_v2(fileURL.path, &db, SQLITE_OPEN_READWRITE, nil) == SQLITE_OK else {
        print("error opening database")
        sqlite3_close(db)
        db = nil
        return
    }

    // report success
    print("db copied and opened")
    return
}
```